# ¿Cómo llenar una columna a partir del dato de otra en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde estoy guardando los datos de un empleado y existe una columna donde se ingresa el salario.

La tabla tiene otra columna donde debe ir la cantidad de seguro social que debe cancelar a partir del salario; esta operación la logre realizar con columnas calculadas.

El problema es que SQL no permite hacer uso de estas columnas calculadas para utilizarlas y generar otra columna.

Es decir, quiero tener otra columna que se llame `salarioliquido` al hacer el descuento del salario restándole el `segurosocial`. Estuve analizando hacer un trigger que se dispare justo al ingresar el salario pero no sé si es la mejor opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y si creas una vista?

Comment: de dónde sacarías el ``segurosocial``

Comment: ¿Por que el SQL no te lo permite? ¿Tienes un error? ¿Cuál? por otro lado si ya hiciste una columna calculada, no puedes construir otra para  `salarioliquido` replicando el calculo de `segurosocial`

Comment: Bueno con respecto de donde sacaria el segurosocial pues es una pequeña operacion que realiza la columna calculada a partir de el dato que se ingresa en la columna salario.

Comment: Por otra parte intente utilizar la columna calculada del Seguro social para crear una nueva columna calculada y no me lo permite, y por cierto que la columna calculada la programe como PERSISTED para que sea un dato real dentro de la base.

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código de la definición de tu tabla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: por alli no entendi bien el problema pero no bastaria con replicar el pequeño calculo basado en salario que calcula el valor del segurosocial y luego restarla del salario.